# Bash alert monitoring, Send alert n times then pause for n minutes

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

We have a bash script based alert monitoring system in place which runs every 5 mins through crontab and sends a email notification if any error is found.

But because of this our mailboxes get flooded with error emails when something goes wrong.

Our requirement is simple

1. Run cronjob for log monitoring every minute.
2. send alerts as it occurs only three times but these alerts should have occurred  only within a interval of 3 mins. If alert have occurred with a time interval of 10 mins or more then no need to pause the email alerts
3. once alerts have occurred 3 times within a 3 mins time interval the email notification should pause or stop for atleast 20 mins(so that our mailboxes do not get flooded). And then the monitoring script should start functioning again after 20 mins as usual.

I have been working on the code to keep track of how many times the alert has been generated and stop sending msg when alert has been sent 3 times. But I am not able to figure out how to add time based logic to this.

```
error=$(cat error.log | grep "ORA-" | wc -l)

counter=$(/tmp/counter.txt)
counterval=$(cat /tmp/counter.txt | wc -l)

if
   [$error -ge 1] && [$counterval -lt 3]
   then echo "errors in log file"
   echo "1" >> $counter

elif
     [$error -ge 1]
     then echo "1" >> $counter
else
    echo "Nothing to report"

if [$counterval  -e 30]
    then cat /dev/null > $ counter
fi
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)